# R predict - How to format output

Tags: r, predict

I use the predict function to predict the results based on a model.
What I get is a vector of the predicted classes. I want to retrieve the same results but instead of the form

```
1 class_1
2 class_1
3 class_4
4 class_2
```

I want to have the results in the form

```
    class_1 class_2 class_3 class_4
1         1       0       0       0
2         1       0       0       0
3         0       0       0       1
4         0       1       0       0
```

I have tried passing `type=class` and `type=response` but the results are the same.

I am completely new to R and I am still trying to find my way around R's documentation but I think that this is something trivial that I should be able to figure out, though I am pretty stuck.

Comment: What type is your model?

Comment: randomForest, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes.  I was able to get it to produce probabilites in the format you are looking for using `predict(model, x, type='prob')`.

Comment: Is this for Kaggle? I've found a rather long-winded way to do it, but it looks like David's solution is much better, so I'll definitely be using that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After viewing the docs on predict.randomForest at
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf

It appears the valid choices for type are `response`, `prob`. or `votes`.

Using the code below, I was able to reproduce your format, but using probabilities.

```
> predict(model, x, type='prob')
      0     1
1 1.000 0.000
2 0.180 0.820
3 0.138 0.862
attr(,"class")
```

To obtain booleans, another option is you could do one hot encoding on the response results

```
result_classes = list()
for (level in levels(y)){
    result_classes[[level]] <- predict(model, x, type='response') == level
}

data.frame(result_classes )
```

Result:

```
     X0    X1
1  TRUE FALSE
2 FALSE  TRUE
3 FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: It's very close to what I need but instead of the logical 0,1 it produces the probabilities for each class.

Comment: Okay, added an alternative method using one hot encoding to build logicals. There may be a cleaner implementation than mine though. R is not my primary language.